# Charts error in flex ? What you mean by bundle error in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash, desktop

i adding  chart  using dataprovider . And also i used flex bulider SDK 3.0, In installed  `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Flex Builder 3\sdks\3.0.0\frameworks\locale\datavisualization.swc`  also there but  my flex bulider shows error like
Severity and Description    Path    Resource    Location    Creation Time   Id
Unable to resolve resource bundle "charts", So **HOW CAN I SET THE PATH**

```
<mx:ColumnChart x="41" y="68" dataProvider="{stats}" id="columnchart1" width="297" height="262">
  <mx:series>
      <mx:ColumnSeries displayName="Expenses" yField="expenses">
          <mx:fill>
              <mx:SolidColor color="#738994" />
          </mx:fill>

      </mx:ColumnSeries>
      <mx:ColumnSeries displayName="Revenue" yField="revenue">
            <mx:fill>
             <mx:SolidColor color="#a7c8d8" />
          </mx:fill>
      </mx:ColumnSeries>
      <mx:ColumnSeries displayName="Profit" yField="profit">
          <mx:fill>
              <mx:SolidColor color="#406374" />  
          </mx:fill>
      </mx:ColumnSeries>
  </mx:series>
</mx:ColumnChart>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're missing the localization (international language stuff) bundles for the charts. You have Flex Builder Pro? In your sdks folder (`/Applications/Flash Builder Beta/sdks/3.3.0/frameworks/locales` for me) you need a `datavisualization_rb.swc` file. If it is missing, reinstall the sdk from the dvd or something.

Comment: i used Adobe flex builder3 sdk3 . i find out that location datavisualization_rb.swc is not here . But lib folder datavisualization.swc there . so i tried copy datavisualization file to locales location but again shows errors

Comment: Make sure that file is in each of the locale folders too. So, put it in en_US, etc.

Comment: yes, i copied datavisualization_rb.swc to all en_US and ja_JP ..floder. After that i changed location in builder Project->properties->Flex compiler  changed path like -locale=English,Japan,Arabic,Dutch,India -source-path=locale/{locale} Because for multilanguage but shows same errors , So kindly give any idea to  me  Sean Clark Hess

Comment: Sorry, that was my only idea.

Answer (score 0):

After you made the changes suggested by Sean, what I would recommend is. remove the sdk from the compiler and Add it again and re comile it. Chances are it mi